# ¿Cómo puedo verificar que los elementos dentro de un array list son todos iguales o son diferentes?

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy ingresando algunos datos en un arreglo y quiero comparar e informar cuando todos los elementos sean iguales, y cuando al menos uno sea diferente por favor

pensé en algo así pero no me sale

```
 for(int i=0; i<lados.size();i++){
    for(int y=i; y<lados.size();y++){
    if (lados.get(i)!=lados.get(y)){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No son iguales");
    } else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "son iguales");               
           }
```

Comment: Que es lo que no sale, yo lo veo bien , que eslo que esperas obtener

Comment: Al ejecutar no me da el resultado que yo espero...
Ejemplo de mi arrayList (5,6,7,8) este no tiene todos los elementos iguales, pero (4,4,4,4..) sí tiene todos los elementos iguales y yo quiero algo así que me diga que sí son todos iguales o no, pero no me funciona. Ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no salis del loop.

Te recomiendo hacer una funcion como la siguiente

```
function sonIguales(lados) {
  for(int i = 0; i < lados.size(); i++){
   for(int y = i + 1; y < lados.size(); y++){
    if (lados.get(i) != lados.get(y)){
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;               
}
```

de esa manera la función termina ni bien encuentra dos diferentes

Aparte fijate que le suma 1 a `y` para no comparar con sigo mismo

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean iguales = true;
int num = lados.get(0);

for(int i=1;i<lados.length();i++)
{
   if(num != lados.get(i))
   {
      iguales = false;
      break;
   }
}

if(iguales)
{
   //Imprime todos son iguales
}
else
{
   //Imprime hay elementos desiguales
}
```

Por defecto la **variable iguales** toma el valor de **true** y guardo el primer elemento del arreglo en la **variable num**, empiezo a recorrer el arreglo el cual cuando encuentre un elemento diferente al que se guardo en la **variable num** entonces la **variable iguales** pasa a ser **false** y se sale del **ciclo for**, si el arreglo termina de ejecutarse y la **variable iguales** no ha cambiado su valor quiere decir que todos los elementos son iguales, posteriormente se imprime si todos los elementos del arreglo son iguales o no.

Comment: Dime te sirvió ...............

Answer (score 0):

esta funcion te devuelve los elementos que se repitieron, si no devuelve elementos repetidos, todos son iguales, espero te sirva mi aportacion

```
    const num = [1,2,2,5,5,]
var iguales = num.filter(function(item, index, array) {
  return array.indexOf(item) === index;
})
console.log(iguales); 
if(num.length===iguales.length){
console.log('Elementos iguales')
}else{
console.log('Elementos no son iguales')
}
```